# How to import classes in other modules to Jersey?

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish

I want to create a Java project with two modules. One is the module for data analysis and another one is the module for creating a restful server so that I can do data analysis remotely. The structure is as follows:

```
├── MyProject
|   ├── Module 1: classA
|   └── Module 2: 
|            └── HelloWorld (resource class)
|            └── MyApplication (configuration class)
```

In module 2 I use Jersey.(I am a green hand on it) And I use **glassfish** and **Jersey** to build it. (I refer to [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service-on-glassfish-application-server.html)).

I imported the classes in module 1 to the resources class in module two

```
import module1.classA

public class HelloWorld {

    classA a;

    public HelloWorld(){

        classA a = new classA();

    }

    @GET
    @Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getClichedMessage(@QueryParam("test") String test){

        return a.data_analysis()

    }
}
```

However I get a exception as follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: module1.classA;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$4.run(ReflectionHelper.java:309)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.ReflectionHelper$4.run(ReflectionHelper.java:306)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkResourceClassFields(IntrospectionModeller.java:210)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:137)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:111)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:744)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:400)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:163)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:323)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:320)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:310)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5704)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5946)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:108)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:744)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:400)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:163)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:323)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:320)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:310)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5704)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5946)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
Startup of context /test_gf_war_exploded failed due to previous errors]]
```

Which shows that the class in module1 is not found.

I am wondering how to deal with it. And if my framework for realizing it is wrong, what is the right method to import others modules to Jersey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access `Module 1` resources in `Module 2` you need to add `Module 1` to the Module Dependencies of `Module 2`. Select `Open Module Settings` in the context menu and add the module in the `Dependencies` tab.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, finally the problem seems to be solved by modifying  the setting of artifact. ( You are right still it is a dependency problem.)